# Is there a gem to test Redis logic in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, redis

Like Database cleaner, or the default clearing of the data store after a test run. I searched and couldn't find one. It could be either a separate test data store or just something simple that namespaces all Redis commands into a test namespace.

If anyone knows of any lemme know, otherwise I'll write one and OS it :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When working with rails and redis I use a different redis db or [namespace](http://github.com/defunkt/redis-namespace) for the different environments. The setup is very simple and similar to ActiveRecords database config.

First, create a config: (namespace version commented out)

```
#config/redis.yml
default:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
development:
  db: 0
#  namespace: appname_dev
test:
  db: 1
#  namespace: appname_test
production:
  db: 2
  host: 192.168.1.100
#  namespace: appname_prod
```

Then load the config and connect to redis through an initializer:

```
#config/initializers/redis.rb
REDIS_CONFIG = YAML.load( File.open( Rails.root.join("config/redis.yml") ) ).symbolize_keys
dflt = REDIS_CONFIG[:default].symbolize_keys
cnfg = dflt.merge(REDIS_CONFIG[Rails.env.to_sym].symbolize_keys) if REDIS_CONFIG[Rails.env.to_sym]

$redis = Redis.new(cnfg)
#$redis_ns = Redis::Namespace.new(cnfg[:namespace], :redis => $redis) if cnfg[:namespace]

# To clear out the db before each test
$redis.flushdb if Rails.env == "test"
```

Remember to add 'redis-namespace' to your Gemfile if your using that version.

Comment: jlundqvist, does putting `$redis.flushdb if Rails.env = "test"` in the config/initializers/redis.rb automatically clean the redis db after each test? or do I have to do somethign about it?

Comment: @Meena it cleans the redis db before each test-run, not each individual test

Comment: It should be Rails.env == "test" (double equals) if you want to keep Rails.env working! I made the edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [fakeredis](https://github.com/guilleiguaran/fakeredis). It is an fake redis implementation written in pure ruby.

Comment: I have used fakeredis and its great, but I have a weird problem. Everything works fine except when I store array in set, it stores whole array as string, don't know why.
For eg, if I do $redis.sadd("odd_no", [1,3]) then
$redis.smembers("odd_no") yields ["[1, 3]"].
Btw adding each value (1 & 3) individually works fine.
Any solution??

Answer (score 3):

Oh, yes there is.
I use it in all of my projects where I need to test Redis logic.

it's very useful, and it's not on the same database as your local development so the data has no danger of being "mixed"

there it is: I put this code in my spec_helper.rb file, but you can put it in your test_helper.rb if you are using test unit.

```
# ==========================> Redis test configuration
REDIS_PID = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pids/redis-test.pid"
REDIS_CACHE_PATH = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/cache/"

Dir.mkdir "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pids" unless Dir.exists? "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pids"
Dir.mkdir "#{Rails.root}/tmp/cache" unless Dir.exists? "#{Rails.root}/tmp/cache"

config.before(:suite) do
  redis_options = {
    "daemonize"     => 'yes',
    "pidfile"       => REDIS_PID,
    "port"          => 9736,
    "timeout"       => 300,
    "save 900"      => 1,
    "save 300"      => 1,
    "save 60"       => 10000,
    "dbfilename"    => "dump.rdb",
    "dir"           => REDIS_CACHE_PATH,
    "loglevel"      => "debug",
    "logfile"       => "stdout",
    "databases"     => 16
  }.map { |k, v| "#{k} #{v}" }.join('\n')
  `echo '#{redis_options}' | redis-server -`
end

config.after(:suite) do
  %x{
    cat #{REDIS_PID} | xargs kill -QUIT
    rm -f #{REDIS_CACHE_PATH}dump.rdb
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I would mark both of your answers correct if I could :)